# Getting model instance when using QuerySet.values()

Tags: django, django-orm

Let's say I have two models, one referencing the other:

```
class Shelf(models.Model):
     pass

class Book(models.Model):
     shelf = models.ForeignKey(Shelf)
```

I'd like to use `values()` on a QuerySet of `Book` instances:

```
In [1]: Book.objects.create(shelf=Shelf.objects.create())
Out[1]: <Book: Book object>

In [2]: Book.objects.values()
Out[2]: [{'id': 1, 'shelf_id': 1}]
```

The problem is that the returned dictionaries contain just the primary keys of the related `Shelf` instances instead of the instances themselves. Is there a way to get the actual instances in a single query? E.g.:

```
In [2]: Book.objects.values()
Out[2]: [{'id': 1, 'shelf': <Shelf: Shelf object>}]
```

The reason I'm using `values()` is so that I can merge two QuerySets for different models which I want to sort and render into a single table in a view.

Comment: what do you mean by 'actual models'? You can set the model name in the dictionary after you call `values()`: `book_vals = Books.objects.all(); book_vals['model_name'] = Book.__name__`

Comment: @alfonso.kim I would like to get model instances as values in the dict. I updated the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a very similar output by a generator with `.get()` like this:

`(Shelf.objects.get(id) for id in Book.objects.values_list("shelf"))`

Comment: No! Definitely not! :) That would send a separate query to the DB for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values):

> If you have a field called foo that is a ForeignKey, the default
>   values() call will return a dictionary key called foo_id, since this
>   is the name of the hidden model attribute that stores the actual value
>   (the foo attribute refers to the related model).

I don't think it is possible with the default `values()` implementation. You can create a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/) and override the `values()` method to create a multi-level dictionary for each `ForeignKey` of the model.